# Android AsyncHttpClient - "Content-Type not allowed!" when downloading files

Tags: android, http, content-type, android-async-http

I'm using the AsyncHttpClient library from http://loopj.com/android-async-http/ and have it calling web services fine to retrieve JSON responses.  I'm now trying to call a web service that streams files back to the client over HTTP.  I'm therefore using the BinaryHttpResponseHandler to capture the byte[] data returned.  However every time I try to call the method it fails, and when examining the Throwable object the exception is 'org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Content-Type not allowed!
'.

I've tried specifying a list of content types to allow as per the docs, but this hasn't made a difference.  I'm mostly streaming PDFs but ideally I don't want to specify a list of content types, I want to be able to download any file type.  The code I'm using is as follows :

```
AsyncHttpClient httpClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
String[] allowedContentTypes = new String[] { "application/pdf", "image/png", "image/jpeg" };
httpClient.get(myWebServiceURL, new BinaryHttpResponseHandler(allowedContentTypes) {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(byte[] binaryData) {
        // ....
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable error, byte[] binaryData) {
        // ....
        Log.e("Download-onFailure", error.getMessage()); 
    }
});
```

I've also tried not specifying any content types, just using :

```
new BinaryHttpResponseHandler()
```

but this made no difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ignore me, there is nothing wrong with BinaryHttpResponseHandler. The files I'm pulling from the web service are PDF, JPG, PNG etc so I had allowed content types of application/pdf, image/jpeg, image/png. However I used WireShark to inspect the HTTP response headers coming back and found the content type was actually 'text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1'. Once I added this to the allowed content types everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

add following method to see the "not accepted" content

```
public void sendResponseMessage(HttpResponse response) {
    System.out.println(response.getHeaders("Content-Type")[0].getValue());
}
```

for me was the result "image/png;charset=UTF-8"

then add it ;)

Comment: simple way to know the incoming content-type. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found the code in `BinaryHttpResponseHandler.java` follows:

```
boolean foundAllowedContentType = false;
for(String anAllowedContentType : mAllowedContentTypes) {
    if(anAllowedContentType.equals(contentTypeHeader.getValue())) {
        foundAllowedContentType = true;
    }
}
```

It seems that you must lists all kind of types you want to receives.

Answer (score 1):

You can check exactly what kind of file is returned by your web services. Just overwrite the `onFailure` in your `BinaryHttpResponseHandler` like this:

```
@Override 
public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] binaryData, Throwable error) 
{ 
    Log.e(TAG, "onFailure!"+ error.getMessage());
    for (Header header : headers)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, header.getName()+" / "+header.getValue());
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `*/*`

```
String[] allowedContentTypes = new String[] { "*/*", "application/pdf", "image/png", "image/jpeg" };
```

Comment: have you checked by dumping the pcap data?

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with pcap.  I can see the content downloaded within a browser, and the same web method works fine on my iOS app.

Answer (score 0):

Adding "application/octet-stream" as a allowed type worked for me!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I encounted a same problem.I checked the source. URL is following

https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/loopj/android/http/BinaryHttpResponseHandler.java

android-async only support two Content-Type:"image/jpeg","image/png"。

I think if you need Content-Type is others,you need override the class.

Answer (score 0):

just do like this:

```
String[] allowedContentTypes = new String[] { "image/jpeg;charset=utf-8", "image/jpeg;charset=utf-8" };
```

it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem. After digging a while came up with solution to add ".*" at the end of content types in order to prevent specifying all combinations of actual content-types and charsets:

```
String[] allowedContentTypes = new String[] { "application/pdf.*", "image/png.*", "image/jpeg.*" };
```